# Recompress PostgreSQL custom format dump file -Z 6 to -Z 9

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

Could anybody explain to me how to recompress pgdump file in a custom format without restoring it?

My workaround is the main database with replication, 5 nodes in total, with approx size about 300GB, I'm using one for slave replicas for creating dump file with -Z 9 it took about 4 hours, with -Z 6 it took about 2 hours. The problem in using -Z 9 is that it took too much time and replica became way too behind master node, that is why I'm using -Z 6 compression. I can't add one more node just for making the dump files.

Restore the database on dump storage and create the new dump file better compression is no option due to low resources on the dump storage to restore the database.

I'm already tried to compress the pgdump file with bz2 or 7z but I got difference only 1 GB on the total size of pgdump file about 40GB. If I use -Z 9 compression I got pgdump file size about 32 GB.

Is there any option to use pg_restore and pg_dump and recompress pgdump file with -Z 6 compression to -Z 9 compression?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a simple way to rewrite a PostgreSQL dump file with higher compression, but what about creating the dump with `-Z 0` and later compressing it with `gzip` or something similar?

That would make `pg_dump` as fast as possible, and you could still have compression.

Comment: Hi Laurenz,
I've tried to use `-Z 0` but I face some issues, need to add storage just for store backups before import dump file to our dev servers to check the bug if dev team required some data from prod database to reproduce the bug.
I discussed the current issue with CTO, he suggests to leave it with `-Z 6` and keep less pgdump files till we upgrade our storage server. 
So I guess this issue will be closed without a solution.
Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Storage space is cheap!